# Converting Json to Csv issue

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I am trying to convert a JSON to CSV with JavaScript. The problem is I keep getting the error:  Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys.

I only want the 'features.attributes' keys and values from the data. I have no problem getting the keys but the values seems to be a problem. Any help wuld be appreciated.

json

```json
{
     "displayFieldName": "label",
     "fieldAliases": {
      "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID",
      "label": "label",
      "west": "west",
      "east": "east",
      "north": "north",
      "south": "south",
      "scale": "scale",
      "title": "title",
      "edition": "edition",
      "available": "available",
      "physHold": "physHold",
      "primeMer": "primeMer",
      "projection": "projection",
      "publisher": "publisher",
      "datePub": "datePub",
      "color": "color",
      "recId": "recId",
      "note": "note",
      "location": "location",
      "bathLines": "bathLines",
      "bathInterv": "bathInterv",
      "instCallNo": "instCallNo",
      "setTitle": "setTitle",
      "sheetId": "sheetId",
      "digita": "digita",
      "titleAlt": "titleAlt",
      "digHold": "digHold",
      "miradorURL": "miradorURL",
      "iiifURL": "iiifURL",
      "Shape_Length": "Shape_Length",
      "Shape_Area": "Shape_Area"
     },
     "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
     "spatialReference": {
      "wkid": 102100,
      "latestWkid": 3857
     },
     "fields": [
      {
       "name": "OBJECTID",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
       "alias": "OBJECTID"
      },
      {
       "name": "label",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "label",
       "length": 50
      },
      {
       "name": "west",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
       "alias": "west"
      },
      {
       "name": "east",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
       "alias": "east"
      },
      {
       "name": "north",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
       "alias": "north"
      },
      {
       "name": "south",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
       "alias": "south"
      },
      {
       "name": "scale",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
       "alias": "scale"
      },
      {
       "name": "title",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "title",
       "length": 55
      },
      {
       "name": "edition",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "edition",
       "length": 85
      },
      {
       "name": "available",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeSmallInteger",
       "alias": "available"
      },
      {
       "name": "physHold",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "physHold",
       "length": 3
      },
      {
       "name": "primeMer",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeSmallInteger",
       "alias": "primeMer"
      },
      {
       "name": "projection",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "projection",
       "length": 19
      },
      {
       "name": "publisher",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "publisher",
       "length": 33
      },
      {
       "name": "datePub",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeSmallInteger",
       "alias": "datePub"
      },
      {
       "name": "color",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeSmallInteger",
       "alias": "color"
      },
      {
       "name": "recId",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "recId",
       "length": 30
      },
      {
       "name": "note",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "note",
       "length": 254
      },
      {
       "name": "location",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "location",
       "length": 254
      },
      {
       "name": "bathLines",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "bathLines",
       "length": 5
      },
      {
       "name": "bathInterv",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "bathInterv",
       "length": 50
      },
      {
       "name": "instCallNo",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "instCallNo",
       "length": 50
      },
      {
       "name": "setTitle",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "setTitle",
       "length": 50
      },
      {
       "name": "sheetId",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
       "alias": "sheetId"
      },
      {
       "name": "digita",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "digita",
       "length": 8000
      },
      {
       "name": "titleAlt",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "titleAlt",
       "length": 8000
      },
      {
       "name": "digHold",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "digHold",
       "length": 8000
      },
      {
       "name": "miradorURL",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "miradorURL",
       "length": 8000
      },
      {
       "name": "iiifURL",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
       "alias": "iiifURL",
       "length": 8000
      },
      {
       "name": "Shape_Length",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
       "alias": "Shape_Length"
      },
      {
       "name": "Shape_Area",
       "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
       "alias": "Shape_Area"
      }
     ],
     "features": [
      {
       "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": 1,
        "label": " ",
        "west": -5.8263888899999996,
        "east": -5.7838888900000001,
        "north": 35.770000000000003,
        "south": 35.814166669999999,
        "scale": 5000,
        "title": "Port de Tanger",
        "edition": " ",
        "available": 1,
        "physHold": "yes",
        "primeMer": 131,
        "projection": " ",
        "publisher": " ",
        "datePub": 1908,
        "color": 31,
        "recId": "agsmap026454",
        "note": "\\\\ $a Relief shown by form lines and hachures. Depths shown by bathymetric isolines and soundings. | \\\\ $a \"Nota, le de\u0301tail de la ville, emprunte\u0301 au plan local espangnol, a e\u0301te\u0301 rectifie\u0301 par la triangulation et le nivellement effectue\u0301s par la",
        "location": " ",
        "bathLines": " ",
        "bathInterv": " ",
        "instCallNo": " ",
        "setTitle": "French Charts",
        "sheetId": 21511,
        "digita": "agsmap026454",
        "titleAlt": "Tangier, port, 1908",        
        "Shape_Length": 21584.807399988174,
        "Shape_Area": 28676605.202176783
       },
       "geometry": {
        "rings": [
         [
          [
           -648590.64440000057,
           4269019.7031000033
          ],
          [
           -648590.64440000057,
           4275081.0283999965
          ],
          [
           -643859.56599999964,
           4275081.0283999965
          ],
          [
           -643859.56599999964,
           4269019.7031000033
          ],
          [
           -648590.64440000057,
           4269019.7031000033
          ]
         ]
        ]
       }
      }
     ]
}
```

**js**

```
function exportJSONToCSV(objArray) {
    var arr = typeof objArray !== 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    
    var str =
      `${Object.keys(arr[0])
        .map((value) => `"${value}"`)
        .join(',')}` + '\r\n';
    var csvContent = arr.reduce((st, next) => {
      console.log(next);
      st +=
        `${Object.values(next)
          .map((value) => `"${value}"`)
          .join(',')}` + '\r\n';
      return st;
    }, str);
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvContent);
    element.target = '_blank';
    element.download = 'export.csv';
    element.click();
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the CSV to look like?

Comment: features.attributes keys as the column headers, features.attributes values as the values for each column.

Comment: Not to discourage you from learning how to do it on your own, but there are great libraries on NPM that already do this and handle all the data formatting edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var json = ... // YOUR JSON
var features = json.features;
var isFirstIterationCompleted = false;
var csv = '';
features.forEach(e => {
    var attributesKeys = Object.keys(e.attributes);
    if (!isFirstIterationCompleted) {
        csv += attributesKeys.join(';') + '\n'; // separated by semicolon
        isFirstIterationCompleted = true;
    }

    attributesKeys.forEach(a => {
        csv += e.attributes[a] + ';';
    });

    csv += '\n';
})

console.log(csv);
```

Comment: no sorry, does not parse correctly, some of the field values are not correct. Thank you for your efforts though!

Comment: post an example of the csv you want..by the json you posted, the csv is correct if you want, as you said: "features.attributes keys as the column headers, features.attributes values as the values for each column"